# echoing request with fputs

Tags: php, request, echo, fputs

I'm using the code below, to post a request to an API. For debugging purposes: is there a way to echo the full Request (including the Header) that is sent by this code?

```
$data = http_build_query($requests);
        $url = parse_url($urlfull);
        $host = $url['host'];
        $path = $url['path'];
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://'.$host, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if ($fp){
            fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Pragme: no-cache\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-length: ". strlen($data) ."\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n");
            fputs($fp, $data);
            $result = '';
            while(!feof($fp)) {
                $result .= fgets($fp, 4096);
            }
        }
        else { 
        $errors = array(
            'status' => 'err', 
            'error' => "$errstr ($errno)"
            );
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

Comment: try to use var_dump();

Comment: That only outputs "resource(28) of type (stream)"